# Is it possible to use lambda layers with zappa?

Tags: django, opencv, aws-lambda, zappa, aws-lambda-layers

I want to deploy my wagtail (which is a CMS based on django) project onto an AWS lambda function. The best option seems to be using `zappa`.

Wagtail needs opencv installed to support all the features.

As you might know, just running `pip install opencv-python` is not enough because opencv needs some os level packages to be installed. So before running `pip install opencv-python` one has to install some packages on the Amazon Linux in which the lambda environment is running. (`yum install ...`)

The only solution that came to my mind is using [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to properly install opencv.

But I'm not sure whether it's possible to use lambda layers with projects deployed by zappa.

Any kind of help and sharing experiences would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/688) that is ready to merge, but needs additional user testing.

The older project has a pull request that [claims layer support has been merged](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1716)

Feel free to try it out and let the maintainers know so documentation can be updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any other solution? Is there any other way to use opencv with zappa?

Comment: Yes, you can use Zappa and deploy a container